# How to create an address of solana by using python?

Tags: python, solana

I want to generate the address of solana by using python how could I do that?

Comment: Be more specific. What do you mean by 'an address of solana'?

Comment: I want to generate an address in solana by using python like in web3.py we create an ethereum account/address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, an address may be many things... for example:

1. System owned accounts are 'addresses'
2. Program Derived Accounts are 'addresses'
3. Program Owned Accounts are 'addresses'

For Python, there is a Python [SDK](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py) I've used that supports creation of all these